# How can I rearrange a LinkedList in Java without changing the data fields, only by rearranging the links?

Tags: java

So first of all, I just started learning about LinkedLists, so I'm sorry if I say something about it and it's totally wrong. I have an assignment where I have to write a method to switch the pairs of a LinkedList. If I have a list [3, 7, 4, 9], it would change to [7, 3, 9, 4] after the method. I'm not allowed to change any of the data fields of the nodes nor can I construct any new nodes. I'm trying to understand how LinkedLists work. So far this is what I have:

```
public void switchPairs() {
    if (front == null)
        return;
    ListNode current = head;
    ListNode next = head.next;
    current.next = null;

    next.next = current;

}
```

Right now I'm still trying to figure out how I can swap the first two values. My reasoning is that I can assign a new ListNode variable called current to the head, and then another new ListNode variable called next to head.next. Then I can assign the node after current to be null. Then that list is separate from the next variable that I created and I can assign the node after next to be current. But that doesn't work. So how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the code below:

```
public void switchPairs() {
if (front == null)
    return;

ListNode current = head;
ListNode nextNode = head.next;
current.next = nextNode.next;
head = nextNode; 
head.next = current;
```

}

Hope this algorithm will help...

1. Assign the head node into the one temp node
2. Assign the head's next node into the another temp node
3. Replace the step 1's next node with the step 2's next node
4. Assign the head next node with the node created on step 1
5. Assign the head node with the node created on step 2

Comment: You are modifying  `head` in a generic method. If OP wants to pass `4,9` as in his example, this method will alter `head`. It is switching first two nodes.

Comment: Yeah this is the example only to swap first two nodes considering the first node is the head node... you may follow the same approach to swap others

Comment: Are you looking to have the whole implementation or would you like to proceed further by following that algorithm?

Comment: So my assignment requires the whole list to be switched. So basically swap the first and second elements, then the third and fourth, and so on. But I think I will try to proceed by following this algorithm, thank you!

Comment: I was able to solve the assignment thanks to the help of this algorithm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow as below.

```
1. While temp is not null && temp1 is not null
      1. Swap links of temp and temp1
      2. Move temp to temp1.next
      3. Move temp1 to temp.next if temp is not null 
                                 else make temp is null
```

swap two node links is as below. [switchPairs(temp, temp1)]

```
 1. newTemp = temp
 2. temp.link = temp1.link
 3. temp1.link = newTemp
```

Let's say

data|link is the pattern I am using here.

```
temp = 3|linkX 

temp1 = 5|linkY

newTemp = temp = Points to the address of Temp

temp.link = 3|linkY [temp.link = temp1.link]

temp1.link = 5|AdrOfTemp [temp1.link = newTemp]
```

If you still have doubts, please post your helper method which calls this function. I doubt that you may missed to switch the temp nodes.